# How to design order schema for multiple products?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have to design a schema in such a way that I can store user id and  their order which can be multiple products  like bread, butter plus in addition to that I want to store the quantity of product ordered, please guide.

Comment: This site is not a good place to look for guiding/mentoring.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to provide you with a real solution to your problem as designing a NoSQL DB structure depends on how you want to access your data. You can keep orders as nested/embedded documents in the User model or store them in a separate collection. In the first case, you will have all the data in one requests, but you will not be able to query and receive orders, that match certain criteria as you will get all orders including those that match. And then you would need to filter them out. Or you could use aggregation to get exactly what you need. 
However, there is a limitation to keep in mind. MongoDB document has a [size limitation - 16 megabytes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/). Since users may have very many orders, you can reach the document size limit for some users for sure. Aggregation also has a limitation - [Pipeline stages have a limit of 100 megabytes of RAMe](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Aggregation-Pipeline-Operation) but you can override it.

Having orders in a separate collection would require you to separately load them for users. While it is one more request, it will give you more flexibility in terms of how you query them.

Then, of course, create/update operations are also done differently for both cases.

My advice would be that you carefully design your application first - what data you need and where you will show it, how you create/update it. It will give you a better idea and chances are that relational DB will be a better choice for what you need (though absolutely not necessary).